# Codename one Picker change date format

Tags: datepicker, codenameone

Is it possible to change the date format on the codename one Picker to show only the year in full e.g 2014 or 1990 ? As of now it has this date format "M/d/yy" which in turn gives a date such as "Oct 15 2014" to "10/15/14". Is there a way to change this date format?

Answer (score 0):

This looks differently on the devices. The picker is implemented natively there.

Comment: Am not saying your answer is a bad one, you have helped me a lot when it comes to codename one, am just saying have to another find a way to manage to get what I need my app to do as I work with what it does for now. All your answers have always helped me on.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is still looking, The Picker has a getDate(), with this you can use the CNILIB on formating.

```
String datestring=(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")).format(picker.getDate())
```